# data.table::fwrite behaving strange when saving file names

Tags: r, data.table

I have a very large data frame and I am doing multiple operations on a subsets of columns in `lapply`, which includes exporting the subset using `data.table::fwrite`

I have multiple columns which the same letters but are different cases (for example Co2 and CO2). When I obtain the column names and run the process in `lapply` using `dplyr::select` the correct columns are selected (i.e. the correct cases are selected), but when I export the data, some of the exported file names have the incorrect case, while others have the correct case.

For example, below is an example data frame

```
test_df <- data.frame('CO2' = c(1,2,3,4,5),
                      'Co2' = c(6,7,8,9,10)) 

  CO2 Co2
1   1   6
2   2   7
3   3   8
4   4   9
5   5  10
```

Below is the code I use to select the columns used in `lapply` followed by a simple subset of the datasets using `lapply` (note the output is as would be expected).

```
test_colnames <- test_df %>% colnames()  

lapply(test_colnames, function(x){
  
  var_name <- all_of(x)
    
  export <- test_df %>% 
    select(!!var_name) })

[[1]]
  CO2
1   1
2   2
3   3
4   4
5   5

[[2]]
  Co2
1   6
2   7
3   8
4   9
5  10
```

When I try to export the subsets using the code below I only get one output file (instead of two), which is named CO2, but has data from Co2. Somehow Co2 has been capitalised for the output name (but not the column names) and overwritten the CO2 file.

```
lapply(test_colnames, function(x){
  
  var_name <- all_of(x)
    
  export <- test_df %>% 
    select(!!var_name) 
  
  export %>% data.table::fwrite(paste0(data_directory, "test_out_", all_of(x), ".csv")) })
```

Only one file was output which was named test_out_CO2.csv, but below is the contents of the file.

```
  Co2
1   6
2   7
3   8
4   9
5  10
```

Any ideas for how to fix this?

---

**Edit:** Simplified example, below would output only one file - "testName.txt":

```
library(data.table)
fwrite(mtcars[1:2], "testName.txt")
fwrite(mtcars[3:4], "testname.txt")
```

Comment: I am guessing you are using Windows where filenames are case insensitive. So fwrite is just overwriting the 2nd file.

Comment: I forgot to add, this is not data.table specific, write.table would give you the same 1 file.

Comment: Thanks for the information. Are there anyways to get around this in the lapply loop?

Comment: We can check if the file exists before writing - `file.exists()`. See also, `tolower`, `toupper` functions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not *data.table* specific issue, Windows filenames are case insensitive.

I would suggest to make the column names *very* unique:

```
colnames(test_df) <- make.unique(tolower(colnames(test_df)), sep = "_")
colnames(test_df)
# [1] "co2"   "co2_1"

# ... rest of your code
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks zx8754 for the solution.

Based on the info provided by zx8754 a modified solution which would retain the case of the variable, while making sure the file names are unique for windows would be an if else statement.

```
lapply(test_colnames, function(x){
  
  var_name <- all_of(x)
    
  export <- test_df %>% 
    select(!!var_name) 
  
  if (file.exists(paste0(data_directory, "test_out_", all_of(x), ".csv"))) {
  
  export %>% data.table::fwrite(paste0(data_directory, "test_out_", all_of(x), "_1.csv")) }
  
  else {
    
  export %>% data.table::fwrite(paste0(data_directory, "test_out_", all_of(x), ".csv")) }
  
  })
```